CSP does not report 'form-action' when Report-Only
On a page I've got these response headers
content-security-policy-report-only
    default-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; script-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src https: data:; media-src https: data:; connect-src https:; font-src https:; frame-ancestors 'self'; frame-src https:; form-action 'self'; report-uri https://xxxx.ingest.de.sentry.io/api/xxxx/security/?sentry_key=xxxx; report-to csp-endpoint
report-to
    {"group": "csp-endpoint", "max_age": 10886400, "endpoints": [{"url": "https://xxxx.ingest.de.sentry.io/api/xxxx/security/?sentry_key=xxxx"}], "include_subdomains": true}
reporting-endpoints
    csp-endpoint="https://xxxx.ingest.de.sentry.io/api/xxxx/security/?sentry_key=xxxx"

There's a CSP violation sent to the console:
[Report Only] Refused to send form data to 'https://domain.test.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self'".

But none are sent to the report endpoint (Sentry).
Meanwhile when I replace content-security-policy-report-only with content-security-policy, the violation is enforced and the report is sent.
My diagnostic would be that the XHR to Sentry would not "get out" before the form being sent (and redirected) when no enforcement is done. Am I mistaken?

Interesting, I would've expected an implementation closer to the behavior of the Beacon API, that tries to ensure requests are still made even when the current document unloads. Is this happening across all browsers, or specific ones?

As redirecting behavior of form-action directive is still debated, I'm only viewing this in Chrome-based browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/form-action

I did receive form-action reports with report-only from Chromium browsers recently. I was using report-uri and not report-to.
